# react-router-redux redirect to absolute url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-redux

I'm migrating a react application and I'm trying to split it. Basically, I would like to redirect some client-side react routes to absolute urls (or relative, but at least go with a server roundtrip, where reverse proxying is done)

Note that

- react-router 3.0.0
- react-router-redux 4.0.7
- The app have these urls

  - http://myhost/ => homepage
  - http://myhost/someroute1 => a first route
  - http://myhost/someroute2 => a second route
  - http://myhost/someroute3 => a third route

Everything is inside react right now.

Routing looks like this :

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <Router history={history}>
    <Route path="/" component={Root}>
      <IndexRoute component={Home} />
      <Route path="/someroute1" component={Route1} />
      <Route path="/someroute2" component={Route2} />
      <Route path="/someroute3" component={Route3} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
</Provider>
```

The goal is to redirect, say, routes "/" and "/someroute2" to static urls (server urls). As so :

- http://myhost/ => http://anotherhost/
- http://myhost/someroute1 => keep react routing
- http://myhost/someroute2 => http://anotherhost/anotherroute5
- http://myhost/someroute3 => keep react routing

The question is simple : **is is possible to replace, in a clean way, a react router route with an absolute url ?**

I heard about Redirect and IndexRedirect components, but I can't figure how to use it properly, and, due to a lack of react / react-router, I can't figure if there would be any dangerous side-effects (in history for example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partially based on @brub answer, I've found a solution using a dumb component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class MyRedirectRoute extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    window.location.href = //my url here
  }
  render() {
    return null
  }
}
```

That I pass like this

```
<Route path="/someroute3" component={MyRedirectRoute} />
```

Though, I'm still not aware of a few things :

- Is this a recommended solution ?
- Are there any history side-effect ?
- Is there any better (more react-router) solution than `window.location.href` ? I tried `this.context.history` without any success...

I'm waiting for feedback / better solution before accepting my own answer

Comment: I have tried your solution like this `render{() => this.props.isLoggedIn ? <Checkout /> : <Redirect />}` using the exact same dumb component for Redirect. 

It redirects me to the Checkout page, but before it finishes loading - I'm redirected to Redirect page. Props isLoggedIn is updated to true when I login, so it's not that. Any idea??

Comment: I think @KayaToast's answer is better: " You probably don't need React Router for this. The creator of React Router suggests using the <a> tag. Source: https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/1147 "

Answer (score 5):

Use `Route`'s `render` prop instead of `component`. That way, you can specify a function to be called instead of a component to be instantiated. In the function, perform the navigation the old-fashioned way, using `window.location.href`:

```
<Route 
  path="/someroute2" 
  render={() => {
    window.location.href = "http://anotherhost/anotherroute5";
    return null;
  }} 
/>
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably don't need React Router for this. The creator of React Router [suggests](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1147) using the `<a>` tag.

Answer (score -2):

I haven't tried it but syntactically you could do it like this:

```
<Route 
 path="/someroute2" 
 render={() => <Redirect to="http://anotherhost/anotherroute5" />} 
/>
```

Comment: Thanks :) But it leads to *http://myhost/http:/anotherhost/anotherroute5*

Comment: heh- like i said untried.  i just edited it, you could try pushing the location as above.

Comment: Hum :/ doesn't work. It displays a white window without any error in console

Comment: It seems to do the trick inside `componentDidMount`, see my answer

Comment: Right on- I unedited my bad edit- I didn't think you could call a navigation function from render().  I normally do conditional navigation stuff in sagas.  For this particular use case I would handle the redirect outside the react code if possible (nginx or something).

Comment: *I would handle the redirect outside the react code* yes I did, when i reach url from the bar it's ok. But there are still the cases where <Link> are involved..

Comment: i think you could replace <Link> with <a> and it would hit the same external endpoints.

Comment: That's precisely what I'm trying to avoid. The app I inherited is much more complicated than a few <Link>, it has many places places where the Routes are loaded either by user action, code-driven events, etc.